# How to verify original image's input channels when using Keras load_image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-preprocessing

I am using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_image` to load 3-channel images into a simple classification network. Based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/load_img) for `load_img`, this method will return a 3-channel image **even if the original image had a single channel** (by duplicating the channels, I suppose).

Since it is possible for the user of my application to accidentally provide a single-channel image, this has the potential to fail silently with no way for the user to know why the predictions are bad.

I would therefore like to add a line to my code that makes sure that the original loaded image does indeed have 3 channels, and raise an error otherwise.

Is there a way to catch 1-channel images without loading them twice separately? Is there an alternative method to `load_image` that I can use for loading the images in a way that doesn't change the number of channels?

Comment: doesn't seem like the method provides a check to use. Why do you want to avoid the double loading? Yes, it would increate the processing time, but it only gets done once, so shouldn't be that big of a deal? Unless you are loading millions of images

Comment: This is part of a pipeline that needs to process a large number of images, so I would like to avoid unnecessary processing times. Also, it seems like bad practice. There must be a more elegant way that I am missing.

Comment: well, you could define your own preprocessing function, but that would be extra

Comment: load_img does not cover all possible use cases, you should implement your own loading function using something like PIL or OpenCV.